# Python - Get most recent date in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have to get the most recent date in a dataframe pandas. 
I wrote this code:

```
  df=pd.read_csv('waterquality.csv')
  # Convert date to datetime type
  df['SampleDate'] = df['SampleDate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
  #print(df.SampleDate.max())

  g=df.groupby(['name','beach','ParameterCode']).SampleDate.max()
  print(g)
```

The output is:

```
  [...]
  Seal Beach        Seal Beach Pier     Enterococcus      2018-12-09
                                        Total Coliforms   2018-12-09
```

But the date is not the most recent. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: How working `df=pd.read_csv('waterquality.csv', parse_dates=['SampleDate'])` and then `g=df.groupby(['name','beach','ParameterCode']).SampleDate.max()` ? Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it seems to be working, could you provide an example where it's not:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Seal Beach']*4, 'beach':['Seal Beach Pier']*4, 'ParameterCode':['Enterococcus']*2 + ['Total Coliforms']*2, 'SampleDate':['2018-12-09','2018-12-10','2018-12-09','2018-12-10']})

df

    name        beach      ParameterCode        SampleDate
0   Seal Beach  Seal Beach Pier Enterococcus    2018-12-09
1   Seal Beach  Seal Beach Pier Enterococcus    2018-12-10
2   Seal Beach  Seal Beach Pier Total Coliforms 2018-12-09
3   Seal Beach  Seal Beach Pier Total Coliforms 2018-12-10

df['SampleDate'] = df['SampleDate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.groupby(['name', 'beach', 'ParameterCode']).SampleDate.max()

    name        beach            ParameterCode  
Seal Beach  Seal Beach Pier  Enterococcus      2018-12-10
                             Total Coliforms   2018-12-10
```

Comment: Hi! The most recent date for Seal Beach (from the csv file) are: Seal Beach,Seal Beach Pier,10/10/2018,Enterococcus,=,8,CFU/100ml
Seal Beach,Seal Beach Pier,10/10/2018,Total Coliforms,=,33,CFU/100ml.

Comment: Maybe I found the problem. The date format is %d/%m/%Y" in the csv file, so when I convert the object to datetime format, it gets the day as month. How can I insert the format into "df['SampleDate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')"? Thanks